# delegatecall (assembly) didn't change state variable in Remix with Web3 Provider

Tags: solidity, remix, assembly, delegatecall

I am trying to test proxy pattern in Remix, which connected to my private chain with *Web3 Provider*. By the way, miner is working all the time. After invoking **add function** of Proxy contract, the state variable **total** of Proxy contract has not change. But with *Javascript VM*, it changed as expected.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Proxy {

    address public implement;
    // with Web3 Provider, it didn't change. 
    // but with Javascript VM, It changed as expected.
    uint public total;  

    function changeImpl(address _impl) public returns(bool) {
        implement = _impl;
        return true;
    }

    // according to proxy pattern, this should be fallback function.
    // i change it as named function just for convenience
    function add(uint a, uint b) external {
        address _impl = implement;
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
            let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
        }
    }
}


contract ImplContract {

    address public implement;
    uint public total;

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint) {
        total = a + b;
        return total;
    }
}
```

I am so confused why same code make different outcome. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit

Problem solved. The reason causing the failure is **insufficient gas**.

Comment: Are you sure the transaction was mined? Can you get the transaction receipt and post it here?